# Change tabbar selected item from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am new to Swift (using 4 version) and I want to change tab bar item from another view controller (not tab bar controller).

This is my scheme:
[image: scheme]

From RouterViewController (used for side menu navigation) in didSelectRowAt i'm doing this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainViewController = sideMenuController!

    let tabBarController : TabBarController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! TabBarController

    tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
}
```

It's not throwing any exceptions and debugging shows, that let tabBarController is not null, but it's not changing tab for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your code even called? Set a breakpoint

Comment: like you have to go from item 2 to item 1..?

Comment: Yes, it's called 100%.
From 2 to 1 and back in this case, later will add more.

Comment: Use this:- self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = YourValue

Comment: You are instantiating a new tabBarController, which is never shown because it is not added to the window hierarchy.  Setting the value on this tabBarController has no effect on your current visible tabBarController.  Try Anuraj's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

**or**

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = yourViewController;
self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:yourViewController];
```

Comment: self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can define this variable in the appDelegate:

```
var window: UIWindow?
let tabViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
```

Now you can use the tabViewController variable in all your code and invoke the methods on this, like the method to change page.
For all the methods/variables of the UITableViewController see the documentation at this link:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller

I think that change the variable "var selectedIndex: Int" will solve your problem.